# Make IPython3 behave like Python3 for `type`

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

Consider the following with IPython3:

```
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Jul 28 2015, 13:17:50) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: type([1,2])
Out[1]: list
```

and the same piece of code with Python3:

```
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Jul 28 2015, 13:17:50) 
[GCC 4.9.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type([1,2])
<class 'list'>
```

How can I tweak IPython so that it shows the same output as "pure" Python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to deactivate pretty printing:

```
%pprint
```